# Pop up box in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, popup

I want  to display a popup windo on my rails application... Here is exactly what i want is  . I have the line called "My profile" (for link i used link_to). if user clicks the link the popup should come out and displays the user's profile details.... i tried with :popup => 'true' option but it creates new window. i want some Ajax kind of stuff... can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a ruby-on-rails question. What you need is some javascript library to do that. As mentioned by Salil, lightbox is one such library. Others include:

- [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)
- [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)
- [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)
- [shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html)

I personally tried lightbox, thickbox (no longer supported), colorbox, and shadowbox, and found colorbox to best fit my needs.

Comment: Hey Faisal thank you so much for your answer. i complete this by using "FaceBox" Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

use lightbox to achive it.Rails provide lightbox_helper plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the path I would follow: First, you ["load"](http://api.jquery.com/load/) data from your application with the JQuery load function. For this you can use a normal controller action with a some basic view. Then, you want to put it in a fancy Jquery popup, e.g. [explained here](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/)